# InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-code-deploy

If I try to run deployment from a GitHub project to EC2 Instance using AWS CodeDeploy, I get these error messages from `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log`

```
2022-08-01 11:07:25 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3386)]: master 3386: Spawned child 1/1
2022-08-01 11:07:25 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
2022-08-01 11:07:25 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
2022-08-01 11:07:25 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Archives to retain is: 5}
2022-08-01 11:07:25 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
2022-08-01 11:07:25 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
2022-08-01 11:07:25 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-01 11:07:25 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile
2022-08-01 11:07:26 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3386)]: Started master 3386 with 1 children
2022-08-01 11:07:36 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-01 11:07:36 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile
2022-08-01 11:07:49 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.3.2-1902_deb.
2022-08-01 11:07:49 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(3388)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile
```

The EC2 instance has IAM role assigned:

[image]

**IAM permission policies**

[image]

**IAM Trust Relationships**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                    "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to reboot the ec2 instance and restart the code-deploy agent by command:

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent restart
```

But it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IAM role was missing `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` permission